# how to get raw query json from querydsl using elasticsearch 8.x java api

Tags: elasticsearch

querydsl making elasticsearch 8.x java api

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = SearchRequest.of(srq -> srq.index("test_p")
                    .query(q -> q.functionScore(scriptFunctionScoreQuery))
                    .from(0)
                    .size(50)
                    .timeout("750ms").explain(true));

SearchResponse<ObjectNode> objectNode = this.elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest, ObjectNode.class);
```

How do I view a raw query (json) make of querydsl?

8.x version no longer tostring of searchRequest method not working..

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = SearchRequest.of(srq -> srq.index("test_p")
                    .query(q -> q.functionScore(scriptFunctionScoreQuery))
                    .from(0)
                    .size(50)
                    .timeout("750ms").explain(true));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator generator = JacksonJsonProvider.provider().createGenerator(writer);
searchRequest.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
generator.flush();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```